# How can I round an integer to the nearest 20th?

Tags: python, python-2.7

How can I round integers like this? I've looked into the `round()` function, but it doesn't have what I want.

```
5 > 0
9 > 0
11 > 20
14 > 20
19 > 20
20 > 40
29 > 40
```

Comment: Nearest twentieth?  Or nearest multiple of twenty? One twentieth is 0.05.

Comment: @recursive Nearest 20th

Comment: I think the answer is to floating point divide by 20, round the result and then multipy _that_ by 20.  :-)  `round(x / 20.) * 20`

Comment: 20>40? I think 20 nearest 20th is 20.

Comment: Maybe it means 20 is greater than 40.

Comment: I see the difficulty, as OP's example rounds 20 and 29 up to 40. You would think they would round down to 20.

Comment: And the fact that it refers to rounding integers to the nearest twentieth, when they're all multiples of twentieths already.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Define a lambda:

```
>>> nearest_20 = lambda x: (1 + (x-1)/20)*20 if x % 20 >= 10 else (x/20)*20

>>> nearest_20(5)
0
>>> nearest_20(0)
0
>>> nearest_20(20)
20
>>> nearest_20(11)
20
```

Comment: kinda overkill... but I like it!

Comment: Don't use lambdas to define a function. It doesn't have any advantage over a regular function definition. This makes Guido cry.

Comment: @MarkRansom Other than making Guido cry, what are the disadvatanges it has?

Comment: It could be less readable.  You've been forced to use a ternary conditional operator rather than an if block since lambdas don't support statements.

Comment: @recursive You are right about the current lambda, but when Mark had commented, I had this `nearest_20 = lambda x: (1 + (x-1)/20)*20` as my answer, and I wasn't able to think of disadvantages with it.

Answer (score 5):

What about something like this:

```
round(15.0 / 20.0) * 20
```

Or:

```
round(15.3 / 0.05) * 0.05
```

?

Comment: The first one for the nearest twenty, and the second one for the nearest twentieth.

Comment: @recursive indeed... I couldn't figure out (unambiguously) what the OP wanted

Answer (score 4):

If `x` is the integer you are rounding, this will give you the correct rounding midway as requested in the original question:

```python
round(int((x + 9) / 20) * 20)
```

Assuming you are rounding the integers to the nearest 20:

- 5 =>  0
- 10 =>  0
- 11 => 20
- 14 => 20
- 19 => 20
- 30 => 20
- 31 => 40